# Calculating count of square numbers between two numbers

Tags: java, algorithm

The problem is to find out the squares between two numbers, inclusive of the numbers. The two numbers are in the range between 1 and 10<sup>9</sup>.

```
long numberOne = in.nextLong();
            long numberTwo = in.nextLong();
            int count=0;
            for(long j=numberOne;j<=numberTwo;j++){
                double numSquareRoot=Math.sqrt(j);
                double numFloor=Math.floor(numSquareRoot);
                if(numSquareRoot == numFloor) count++;
            }
```

What changes can be made to work efficiently on large numbers?

Answer (score 12):

## Can be done in \$O(1)\$ time

The count should be:

\$\lfloor{\sqrt n}\rfloor -\lceil{\sqrt m}\rceil + 1\$

or in terms of your program:

```
return Math.floor(Math.sqrt(numberTwo)) - Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(numberOne)) + 1;
```

Comment: I'm not math background. Mind to explain as simple as you could how you get this? And whats that O(1) time? What topic/subject is that?